# How do I propagate error when X+Y=1 and aX+bY=1?

Tags: correlation, error-propagation

I have data for proportions of two diet categories X and Y (from gut samples, n=10) that must sum to 1. I am multiplying each by a different constant (a and b) and then re-calculating the two proportions (e.g. aX/(aX+bY). How do I propagate the error across the two final proportions, given that the proportions are correlated? Also, should I calculate the sample mean first and then convert it using the constants, or convert using the constants for each sample and then calculate their mean? I have looked at a lot of webpages and I am still stumped by both issues.

Comment: Given that $X+Y=1,$ then $Y=1-X$, whence your question reduces to "how to estimate the error in $aX/(aX+b(1-X))  = 1/b - 1/(b + (a-b)X)$ given the error in $X$?"

Comment: Are you saying that, once the expression has been simplified in this way, I can apply the usual rules for error propagation? Also, I am having problems figuring out the precedence in the last of your equivalent expressions. Are there some parentheses missing?

Comment: I don't see that any parentheses are missing. Whether you can apply the "usual rules" depends on what they are, on the value of $a/b$, and the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Perhaps this will illustrate what I meant about the parentheses. If X = 0.95, Y = 0.05, a = 0.1, and b = 0.85, then aX/(aX+bY) = 0.69, aX/(aX+b(1−X)) = 0.69, but 1/b−1/(b+(a−b)X) = -6.1. I'm going wrong somewhere. By the way, I've been struggling with this problem for a few days, so I really appreciate your help. I might need a little more guidance though, if you have the time. By "rules," I meant the rules governing the addition and multiplication, etc of errors. I'd like to hear more about how the value of a/b and the distribution of X affects what I am trying to calculate.

Comment: Sorry about the algebraic error: the right hand side should read $\frac{a}{a-b} \left(1-\frac{b}{(a-b)X+b}\right)$. Although this is undefined when $a=b,$ the ratio on the left hand side then reduces to $aX$. I suspect you can do better than second-order error propagation (the "delta method") by considering the distribution of $X$, but that depends on exactly what $X$ is measuring and how it is distributed in your population.

Comment: OK. Many thanks. I've now run through that right-hand side and read a little about the delta method. With regard to X, the example data I gave above are actually very similar to the real data. X is always between 0.9 and 1 (all guts contain mostly detritus) and the constants are 0.1 and 0.85 for X and Y, respectively (by applying these constants we are correcting for differences in assimilation between the two diet categories). I'm assuming that these are fixed constants, with no error.

Comment: If you have any advice on implementing the Delta method (or an alternative, given my rough description of the distribution of X above), I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Our site has many examples: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+method